# SQL - How to exclude some data from an outer joined table

Tags: sql-server

I've been flummoxed by this problem for some time.  Here is a simplified version of my data:

**Table 1: "Stays" - clients had "stays" from a start date to end date**

```
Stay ID | Client ID | Start Date | End Date
1       | 1         | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31
2       | 2         | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31
3       | 3         | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31
4       | 1         | 2018-03-01 | *Null*
5       | 2         | 2018-03-01 | *Null*
6       | 4         | 2018-03-01 | *Null*
7       | 5         | 2018-03-01 | *Null*
```

**Table 2: "Families" - some clients were part of families from a start date to an end date**

```
ID | Client ID | Family ID | Start Date | End Date
1  | 1         | 1         | 2017-11-01 | 2017-11-30
2  | 2         | 2         | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31
3  | 3         | 2         | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31
4  | 1         | 3         | 2018-03-01 | *Null*
5  | 6         | 4         | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31
```

So I Outer Join Families on Stays.Client ID = Families.Client ID.

Now here is what I am trying to do.  I'm working in Crystal Reports and I want to display everything in the Stays table. Then, **if the client was part of a family at the time of the stay**, I also want to display the Family ID.  If they weren't, I want it to show a null. So the output might look something like this:

```
Stay ID | Client ID | Family ID
1       | 1         | *Null*
2       | 2         | 2
3       | 3         | 2
4       | 1         | 3
5       | 2         | *Null*
6       | 4         | *Null*
7       | 5         | *Null*
```

I've tried a whole bunch of different types of logic to try to get this to happen.  I need to **exclude only the records from Families where there is no overlap of the Start Date and End Dates**, so for example Families record 4, but I need to include all of the clients who have Stays, and correctly identify which  family overlaps with the Stay, for clients who have multiple Family records and/or multiple Stay records (like Client 1).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: When looking for date range overlaps, use this logic: `WHEN Range1.EndDate >= Range2.StartDate and Range1.StartDate <= Range2.Enddate THEN Overlap`.  Incorporate this logic into your Client check. For NULL end dates, use an arbitrary large date, such as '20991231', i.e. `WHEN IsNull(Range1.EndDate, '20991231') >= Range2.StartDate and Range1.StartDate <= IsNull(Range2.Enddate, '20991231')`

Comment: It's not the overlapping range that's the problem.  The problem is **how do I filter out irrelevant families while still including the stays that have no corresponding family?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT
    StayID
    , ClientID
    , StartDate
    , EndDate
    , FamilyID = (SELECT TOP 1 FamilyID FROM tblFamilies WHERE StartDate >= ts.StartDate AND EndDate <= ts.EndDate AND ClientID = ts.ClientID ORDER BY StayID DESC)
FROM tblStays ts ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel like this is so close but there's a problem.  In cases where a client has multiple family records, like Client 1 in my sample data set, using this subquery results in odd behaviour for me.

A given Stay, like Stay ID=3 will get listed twice, once for tblFamilies.ID=1 and it'll give me FamilyID = Null, and then the same stay will be listed again for tblFamilies.ID=4 showing me FamilyID = 3

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what!

Comment: Make sure you *remove* the join the Families table: you don't need it when using the subquery.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That's the thing I've been missing! <3

Comment: Glad to help! Be sure to up-vote this answer so it can help others!